# Асинхронность в Python (бот на aiogram) – некоторые задачи подвешивают бота на время. Почему?

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

Друзья, привет.

Есть VPN. Через API можно создавать ключи, считать ключи на сервере и т.п.

Пишу бота (aiogram). Он должен быть асинхронным. По идеи. Но заметил такую штуку. Когда один пользователь обращается к серверу (например собирает статистику по ключам), то у другого пользователя на время бот замирает.

Почему так? Это ведь разные функции в боте, разные хендлеры. Почему одна задачка (одного юзера) подвешивает всего бота (задачки других юзеров)?

И как собственно это грамотно решить?

Пример подсчёта ключей:

```
client = OutlineVPN(api_url=server[0])
keys_amount = len(client.get_keys())
```

Улучшит ли ситуацию, если я сделаю функцию OutlineVPN асинхронной (async def ...) и буду её вызывать через await ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синхронные функции блокируют основной поток, в это время не могут выполняться асинхронные функции. Асинхронность основана на том, что если асинхронная функция долго чего-то ждет, она не блокирует поток, а на время ожидания (вызов другой асинхронной функции через `await`) отдает управление циклу обработки событий (который уже передает управление другим асинхронным функциям), и только когда ожидание завершено (например, получен ответ от сервера), функция просыпается и дальше работает. Синхронная же функция ни про какие `await` не знает, и никогда не отдает управление асинхронным функциям.

1. Проверьте, может быть есть возможность получить количество ключей без получения самих ключей. Возможно для этого действия время ожидания будет меньше, чем для физического получения всех ключей, и поток будет блокироваться на меньшее время. Но это скорее "костыль".
2. Синхронная функция обернутая в асинхронную не станет сама по себе работать асинхронно, она все так же будет блокировать поток. Можно обернуть ее в `await asyncio.to_thread` (доступно начиная с python 3.9) либо в конструкцию вида `await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, func, *args)` (`func` - ваша синхронная функция), чтобы эта функция выполнялась в отдельном потоке, не блокируя основной поток.

Пример на вашем коде:

```
import asyncio

try:
    from asyncio import to_thread  # added in Python 3.9
except ImportError:

    async def to_thread(func, *args):
        return await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(None, func, *args)

...

async def func():
    client = OutlineVPN(api_url=server[0])
    keys = await to_thread(client.get_keys)
    keys_amount = len(keys)
```

Если инициализация клиента тоже долгая операция, ее тоже придется обернуть в `to_thread`.

Ссылки:

- [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread)
- [awaitable `loop.run_in_executor(executor, func, *args)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)
- пример оборачивания синхронного API клиента в асинхронную обертку с помощью описанного в этом ответе подхода: [transifex_api_2.py](https://github.com/dfint/df-translation-client/blob/03e7cdee50b370cbfef06c4fa1508eeb8e0ae804/df_translation_client/downloaders/transifex_api_2.py)

Comment: спасибо за такое подробное описание. Попробую разобраться!